# Sitecore text search in PDF or Word documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I want to find out if it's possible to configure Sitecore's Lucene search engine to index PDF or Word documents? I've looked on the Sitecore support site at this document (http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc60-65-a4.pdf) but it mentions creating a file crawler class which suggests to me that it's only possible to achieve this by writing custom code. If I *do* need to write custom code to do this, would I also need to have some API in order to extract the text content from PDF documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently had to do something similar on one of my projects.
Have a look at [How to index Word 2003, 2007 and 2010 documents using Lucene.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014337/how-to-index-word-2003-2007-and-2010-documents-using-lucene-net).

I ended up creating a custom indexer which handled MS Office documents (XP,2003,2007 and 2010 format) and PDF documents:

- For indexing XP-2003 MS Office documents you can use `IFilter`s built into the OS (assuming you are using Windows Server 2003 or newer)
- For indexing 2007-2010 MS Office documents you will need to install [Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17062)
- For indexing PDF documents I strongly recommend using [Foxit PDF IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/). It is not free, but does a much better job than the Adobe PDF IFilter.

*Note:* Don't waste your time with Adobe PDF IFilter: it fails to read valid PDF files and is **a lot** slower. Foxit IFilter is designed to take advantage of multi-core CPUs and performs much better on large documents.